# How to set surface sdk scollbar style in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, surface

I have a problem with styling surface scrollbar. Any styles doesnt work. I have tried to style it like common scrollbar, just replace wpf controls to surface controls, but didnt work. http://www.wpfhelper.com/index.php/12-styles-in-wpf/scrollbar/5-wpf-scrollbar-style

Do you have any idea how to apply custom styles for scrollbar???

Please help.

Comment: Right, so surface is just a little different in some ways but not much. However I would recommend for styling a control with so many nested and inherent parts as the scrollbar templates (for vertical/horizontal respectively) that instead of trying a bunch of copy paste stuff from a tutorial for the wpf version, grab a copy of the actual default style template(s) and edit accordingly. In most cases your problems will probably be just little nuance stuff like making `TargetType="{x:Type Button}"` instead be like `TargetType="s:SurfaceButton"` since your success will always lay in the details.

Comment: Can you give me some template examples, because this solution doesnt work?? 
I have done everything what have you typed but no progress :(

Comment: I didn't really give an example, just one of the details that might be stopping you. If I were you, I would put a scrollviewer on the screen and right click -> Edit Templates and work your way into the scrollbar templates to grab the Surface defaults instead of using ones for WPF you find on the net.